# Adding custom javascript to Joomla! template

Tags: javascript, joomla

I´m working in a Joomla! Template and am wondering: Why the javascript in the site doesn´t work if the file is inside a folder in the root folder of the template ? Why only works if the javascript file is on the root folder of the template?

This is when I declared the javascript on my index.php when the file is on a folder:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is when I declared the javascript on my index.php when the file is on the root folder:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by custom .htaccess that could be blocking the file when inside another folder. What happens when you access the js file in the browser directly? Does it resolve?